# how do i make any aspx page as a user control in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have one page called myimage.aspx which creates random captcha image ,

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <%--<img src="MyImagePage.aspx">--%> //using normal page...this is working fine
   <ucImage:ucMyImage ID="myimage" runat="server" /> //using usercontrol this gives me image but following textboxes , buttons ans labels are disappears :(   
   <asp:TextBox id="CodeNumberTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Button id="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit"></asp:Button><br>
   <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="CORRECT!" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
   </div>
   </form>
```

i called that page on my index.aspx page like this `<img src="MyImageControl.ascx">`.
But instead of aspx page i have created it as a usercontrol myimagecontrol.ascx
and put it into index.aspx like   `<ucImage:ucMyImage ID="myimage" runat="server" />`   also add <%@ Register %> tag too, but I'm only able to view image captcha not any other contains of index.aspx page like textbox or others button,
please tell me whats wrong???

Comment: posting some of your code will definitely help..

Comment: posting the user control code will help.

Comment: @visionary - posted in the question

Comment: Ashish, we need the code of your ucMyImage control, not of your page.

Comment: could be some HTML tag not closed properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open the design view and drag your control on the page where ever you want to call it 
Make sure it is in design view.

Comment: I did it as i posted code for usercontrol. <ucImage:ucMyImage ID="myimage" runat="server" /> //this gives me image but following textboxes , buttons ans labels are disappears :(

Comment: When you open the design view of the page do u see the control and your user control

Comment: yes in the design view I'm able to view all the controls and my usercontrol too

Comment: check the source code for this page when loaded in the browser and trace the page as well, The code seems to be alright

Answer (score 0):

From my ASPX page

```
<%@ Register TagName="uc" TagPrefix="uc1"  Src="~/WebUserControl.ascx"%>
<uc1:uc ID="uc" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server">Loaded after UC</asp:Label>
```

From my UserControl

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebUserControl" %>
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

I have no issues what so ever. I don't see why your controls won't render because of the usercontrol. There must something in your codebehind which interferes with the rendering of your controls

Answer (score -1):

Hi :)  I think there may b issue in rendering, Here i am posting my code which is working

For user Control (ascx)

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebUserControl1" %>
<p>
    <img alt="" src=""  runat="server" id="image"/> </p>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1"
    runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

For AspX (Registering User Control)

```
<%@ Register src="WebUserControl1.ascx" tagname="WebUserControl1" tagprefix="uc1" %>
```

For Using the Image Tag in Aspx

```
<uc1:WebUserControl1 ID="WebUserControl11" runat="server" />
```